# PHP, MySQL - How to correctly pass a variable in to a link

Tags: php, mysql

So what I have is:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$loann = $_POST['loann'];
$dater = $_POST['dater'];
$apaid = $_POST['apaid'];
```

... and:

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE _loan SET loana='$loann', dater = CONCAT_WS(',', dater,  '$dater' ), apaid = CONCAT_WS(',', apaid , '$apaid' ) WHERE id=$id");

    echo $id;
```

Everything works fine now the problem shows when I tray to pass the value of $id into:

```
echo ('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=view_details.php?id=$id">');
```

What I would get in the browser would be:

```
mysite.net/view_details.php?id=$id
```

Instead of:

```
mysite.net/view_details.php?id=133
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not use the PHP `header()` function for redirection ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: @Maximus2012 Unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: The variable won't be parsed in a single quote string.

Comment: Can you update the question with the code where you used `header()` to see why it did not work? This seems to be a pretty simple problem so it should work.

Comment: p.s. SQL injection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using a single-quoted string, which doesn't expand variables.  Either use a double-quoted string:

```
"<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"1;url=view_details.php?id=$id\">"
```

or concatenate the strings:

```
'<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=view_details.php?id=' . $id . '">'
```

---

Side note: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.  You should start reading [here](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).